# Unity rigidbody velocity

Tags: unity, physics, movement

**In Unity, what is the correct way to move a game object by modifying the velocity of its rigidbody?**

I'm having some issues with stuttering movement, so I just want to make sure I understand the basic idea. Is the following correct for moving an object vertically down the screen? Should this result in smooth, stutter-free movement?

````csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    [SerializeField] private float speedY = -250;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(
            0,
            speedY *  Time.fixedDeltaTime
        );
    }
}

```
````

Comment: If you multiply a speed by a duration, you get a distance. If you want a velocity, do not multiply by deltaTime.

Comment: But what about "frame independence" ?

Comment: You get that already from the physics engine's integration. By double-dipping on time here, you've taken what *would* be a framerate-independet calculation and broken it, making it framerate-*dependent*.

Comment: Well, that sure would explain a lot of issues I am seeing! I will remove it, and try it out!

Comment: I have also seen people divide by `Time.fixedDeltaTime` (instead of multiplying by it), I assume that's done for dimensional purposes (i.e. using a distance vs a velocity). But I assume that would lead to the same issue as well?

Comment: @Ben You divide by `Time.deltaTime`/`Time.fixedDeltaTime` if you want to convert a value measured over one frame/fixed update to a value in units per second. For example, if your object moved `.1` units in one fixed update, and you're using the default of 50 fixed-updates per second, `.1 / .02 = 5.0 units / second`

Comment: Hm.. to be honest, I don't really understand why multiplying with `Time.fixedDeltaTime` would make my movement "frame dependent" as @DMGregory says. If its a constant, then surely it should scale the value by the same amount each physics step?

Comment: You're making the behaviour dependent on the duration of your physics step. So if you ever change your physics tick rate, suddenly all your velocities are different.

Comment: Right, but since the duration of the physics step is a constant (unless I change it), multiplying with it would not be the cause of stuttering movement, would it?